# Cloudformation S3 BucketEncryption property intermittent fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying a CloudFormation stack with an AWS::S3::Bucket resource that has been failing intermittently ever since I added the [BucketEncryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-bucketencryption) property. The errors I'm getting are as follows:

```
09:27:53 UTC-0500   CREATE_FAILED       AWS::S3::Bucket S3Bucket    A conflicting conditional operation is currently in progress against this resource. Please try again. 
09:27:52 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::S3::Bucket S3Bucket    Resource creation Initiated
09:27:51 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::S3::Bucket S3Bucket
```

Notice how the error happens 1 second after the bucket creation. Some sort of async and/or boto issue maybe? Here's my relevant Cloudformation code:

```
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              KMSMasterKeyID: !If
                - KmsUsed
                - !If
                  - KmsKeyUsed
                  - !Ref KmsKeyId
                  - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
                - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
              SSEAlgorithm: !Ref SSEAlgorithm
```

This has worked with KMS and AES256, but it seems to fail completely randomly. Does anyone know what the underlying problem and/or solution might be? Thanks in advance!